# Any way to verify android build?

Tags: android, security

Is there any way to programmatically verify the software version of a given android environment, and the entity that created that build? Something along the lines of a system level digital signature?

This link suggests that android builds are signed which gives me some hope, but I so far can't find any information as to whether there's some sort of model in place for an app to check the integrity of the system it's running on.

http://www.kandroid.org/online-pdk/guide/release_keys.html#signing

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by _software version of a given android environment_? Are you looking for Android version, model name/number?

Comment: Hi shoe rat, android version might be enough. My general requirement is some mechanism which allows trust in the android environment within which an application is running. For example, if I'm calling system libraries to take a picture how do I know the set of bytes returned

Comment: (continued from comment above) ...is not modified by a custom build to return an arbitray byte array in place of the image representation?

Comment: As long as you are relaying on public APIs, you should be good. No?